# How to make structure like list<string,string,int>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, oop

I'm sorry for the question form, as I don't know what is the name of this concept. If there are any suggestions I'll change it.

I View Model `VMHome` and I need to make one of its props to be like this

```
List<string,string,int>
```

Because I have Iqueryable result and I think that structure would be corresponding. Anyway here is the needed cast message

It is basically Iqueryable like this when using `var`

[image]

after my attempt, it looks like this when using `view model`

[image]

and here is my attempt to make *"immutable struct"*

```
public class VMHome
{
    
    public List<categoryListPostCount> CategoryListPostCount { get; set; }

    // immutable struct
    public struct categoryListPostCount
    {
        public categoryListPostCount(string categoryName, string categoryID, int count)
        {
            CategoryName = categoryName;
            CategoryID = categoryID;
            Count = count;
        }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And here is the faulty usage

```
// ... inject vmHome.. and then 
vmHome.CategoryListPostCount = 
    (from cat in context.postCategories
    join con in context.postContents
    on cat.Id equals con.postCatId
    group new { cat, con } by new { con.postCatId, cat.categoryName } into g
    select new
    {
        //g.Key,
        CategoryName = g.Key.categoryName.ToString(),
        CategoryID = g.Key.postCatId.ToString(),
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: You're creating an anonymous object instead of an instance of your struct. Call your struct constructor instead of `new { ... }`.

Comment: Other's have already pointed out the error (constructing anonymous object instead of struct), but I have another suggestion: You can use `record` to declare your type more succinctly like so: `public sealed record categoryListPostCount(string CategoryName, string CategoryID, int Count)`;

Comment: I agree with @MatthewWatson: using dot net 5 a record *might* be a better alternative than a value tuple or an anonymous type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled would you please show me an example how to use it?

Comment: there are plenty of examples on how to use records online....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting the result of your query in an anonymous type. You should create type of your `struct` using `new VMHome.categoryListPostCount`.

```
vmHome.CategoryListPostCount = 
    (from cat in context.postCategories
    join con in context.postContents
    on cat.Id equals con.postCatId
    group new { cat, con } by new { con.postCatId, cat.categoryName } into g
    select new VMHome.categoryListPostCount
    {
        CategoryName = g.Key.categoryName.ToString(),
        CategoryID = g.Key.postCatId.ToString(),
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

modern dot net supports [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0) (started in dot net framework 4.7) - which basically provides  immutable structs out of the box for up to 8 properies.

So instead of a `List<string,string,int>` you can use `List<(string,string,int)>` - or even better - name your properties: `List<(string CatgoryName,string CategoryId, int Count)>`

Another option would be to use anonymous types which are supported since linq was introduced (meaning .Net 3 IIRC). The downside is that you can't declare a list of anonymous types the same way, you must use `var`.
Sometimes its more convenient, sometimes its less readable.

Also, the struct you've created is not immutable - being immutable means that its properties values can't be changed after it was created. In c# 9 or higher you can use `{get;init;}` for immutable properties, in c# 6 or higher you can use `{get;}` for immutable properties, and in earlier versions you can only achieve immutability by using explicit `readonly` backing fields to properties.